# escape_javascript and single quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in a `some_file.js.erb` file

```
console.log("<%= escape_javascript(translate "I can't do that") %>")
```

Which outputs: `I can&#x27;t do that`

I can't figure out why it is not rendering the single quote correctly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `html_safe` method on the string.

```
console.log("<%= escape_javascript "I can't do that".html_safe %>")
```

Comment: Clarification - we can't use `html_safe` here because it is a translated string.  Imagine it is `escape_javascript(transate "I can't do that")` and the translator could put whatever they want in there.

Comment: Not sure I understand. But I'm guessing you mean that the user enters a string into a form, clicks "translate", and then the server does the translation and then returns the translated string back to the browser inside a js.erb template? And you want to make sure that whatever single quotation marks in the translated string are escaped properly?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what escape_javascript is supposed to do.  From the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/escape_javascript) for `escape_javascript`:

> Escapes carriage returns and single and double quotes for JavaScript segments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the escaped JS won't give you HTML safe code

Try `console.log("<%= escape_javascript "I can't do that".html_safe %>")`

Answer (score 0):

If you plan put some `ruby` code inside javascript,

then `escape_javascript` will not work even if you put `.html_safe` to it.

This works for me,

```
#{sanitize("content with ` single ` quote".gsub("'", "&rsquo;"))}

=> replace all single quotes with `&rsquo;` (html code)
=> sanitize helper to render it properly in view.
```